# Limits of the human body series

Tags: discussion, on-topic

So I started a series yesterday, that seemed like a good idea at the time.

[The limits of human biology: atmospheric tolerances (#1)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21079/the-limits-of-human-biology-atmospheric-tolerances-1)

My plan was/is to create a series (I have a few in mind and I am sure more will come up from other people)

- Atmospheric Tolerances
- Temperature tolerances
- Energy consumption
- Size Limitations

The idea was to have a set of standard questions with well documented, hard-science answers covering the major aspects of H. Sapiens.

---

As was pointed out in the question...these are pretty strictly biology questions, I am not looking for the what ifs of meddling with humanity rather the no kidding capabilities of our physical bodies.

This obviously has value for world builders looking to figure out what a human can do but as was mentioned in the comments these are pretty obviously pure biology questions.

Do we wan't these on our site or should we refer them to biology...I can see answers supporting both so I wanted to see what everyone thought before we got to far.

Comment: Even if the intention is valid, all those questions probably need to be closed-off, possibly after canonical answer(s), as they are off-topic. Much like the question [about realistic religion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/824/is-there-an-effective-way-to-design-a-realistic-religion-for-a-world).

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin please vote on one of the options below, so we can get a consensus on how to handle stuff like this.

Comment: I'm not sure. This is why I did not vote.

Comment: Poll answers are generally frowned upon, though I can't find a specific reference for that.

Comment: I did [something related](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/should-there-be-a-canonical-habitability-question) about planetary habitability a while ago. Looking back, I'm not sure how good of an idea it was. I did it because I saw sooo maaany habitability questions that could all be boiled down to a few things.

Comment: @HDE226868 If there is a better way to handle this discussion thats ok with me

Comment: @PyRulez Take a look at this discussion, its related to the question you asked.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it should be on topic because: (add a comment)

Comment: I believe it's on topic for both sites but more appropriate on Biology SE since you are more likely to get the attention of the specialists of the human body than here.

Comment: I think it should be on topic here because I see connections with it and other science things we've done in the past.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't belong here, don't be lazy you can click on the BiologySE site and ask it over there.

Provide comments below if you have other reasons in mind.

Comment: We want the most accurate info possible which will come from asking on Biology SE.  What we need instead is a solid link to that question and easy way to reference it (which I don't know how to do).  I love the idea of having an SE-based wiki for H. Sapiens related information.